# Hyper-V random shutdown of VMs

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v-server-2012, unexpected-shutdown

I've had my VMs on Hyper-V 2012 (standalone) shutdown/stop randomly.
My VMs are all snapshotted images with the modern.ie windows 7 image (barebone windows 7 with IE9) as the base image. 
I basicly have installed no software, but have a cd/iso that is mounted with the necessary software and a run script that executes on startup

I have 11 VMs w/ 1gb ram each configured identically on a Dell R610 with 1xIntel Xeon E5xx cpu, and 24gb of Ram. The VMs all seem to shutdown around the same time, It seems to happen after they have been running idle for a few hours, so I can't confirm if it's a hypervisor issue or a guest OS issue, but being that they all become 'stopped' around the same time leads me to believe that it's the hypervisor, but again they are identical images and I can't confirm that the Guest OSes aren't doing something that causes them to shutdown.

Basically, where do I start looking to figure out whats causing it? I've had mixed success with connecting to the Hyper-V box with various MMC snap-ins, but I have the HyperV manager and the services manager working (the device manager does not work).

Comment: Check the event viewer in a few guest VMs to see why they shut down and what/who initiated it.

Comment: Check the event logs of the Hyper-V host around the time of the shutdowns as well.

Comment: Did the host reset at that time? Like from patching? ;)

Comment: @tomtom, not sure, but I have HyperV configured to auto-start these VMs on boot

Comment: This might be a stupid question but from your description it seems that you're doing Virtual Desktops -are you sure it's not your users shutting down the VMs ?

Comment: @hyp very sure since they are being used as selenium nodes rather then interactively

Comment: @xeon, the guest VMs appear to have gotten a shutdown ACPI notification, so they aren't just crashing. It looks like HyperV is shutting them down.

Answer (score 8):

Turned out that the VMs were coming up as expired, causing windows to shutdown after an hour. I executed `slmgr -rearm`, and they are good for another 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

If your device manager console does not work, I'm getting the feeling you're running on a Hyper-V host with some major problems.

Comment: That may be the case, but googling around I think that Hyper-V 2012 specifically has device manager removed, and Microsoft expects WMI to be used instead, although I did find a lot of conflicting information.